# How to delete smart pointer to dynamically allocated object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I made an iterator which when dereferenced returns a copy of `std::shared_ptr` that points to a dynamically allocated `std::pair` (created with `new` in the internals of the iterator). The iterator functions as is, but want to free the `pair` at the end of the loop to prevent memory leaks.

```
for (auto it = parser.begin(); it != parser.end(); ++it) {
    shared_ptr<pair<string, string>> record = *it;
    // Analysis of pair
    // delete pair with delete, or reset
}
```

However, I am having trouble freeing the `pair`. I have tried `delete record`, `delete *record`, and `record.reset()`, but none of these will compile.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what smart pointers actually are and do.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: The pair is in a *smart* pointer, i.e. you don't need to manually deallocate memory, the smart pointer will do it for you :)

Comment: Ahh... I understand. I actually feel really silly now. I knew that smart pointers would delete their contents for me but somehow I just forgot haha

Comment: The parser object must ensure the reference count on the `pair` you're iterating over can't hit zero and trigger a `delete` (otherwise the code would already have a race condition and be broken).  So, you could just say `[const] auto& record = **it;` to get a reference to the `pair`, which will be simpler and faster than fiddling with the atomic usage count in a shared pointer twice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/)** are designed to delete automatically the object they manage, once it is no longer needed.  This happens when no shared pointer point anymore to the object (e.g. all the shared pointers pointing to the same object were deleted, or [reset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/reset/) to point to another object).

There is no need to delete it yourself.  By design, there is even no way to delete the object yourself directly, as this might result in some dangling pointers and inconsistencies.

**[`unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/)** are another kind of smart pointers. They are designed to keep ownership of an allocated object and destroy the object when the unique pointer itself is destroyed.

Again, there is no need to delete the object yourself.  `unique_ptr` was created to release you from this duty.  But here you can destroy the managed object, if you want, by [reseting](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/reset/) the pointer.  As the pointer is unique, there is no risk of creating dangling pointers here.

Finally there are also **[`weak_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/weak_ptr/)**.  These do not own an object, but refer to an object managed by some `shared_ptr`.  The idea is that the existence of a weak_ptr does not prevent the object to be deleted.  As the `weak_ptr` does not own an object, it can't delete it, whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

For my smart pointer, which has overloaded operator delete, I use

```
struct DeleteIt
{
        template < typename T >
        void operator() ( const T* ptr ) const
        {
                delete ptr ;
        }

        template < typename T >
        void operator() ( const safeptr< T >& ptr ) const
        {
                delete &ptr ;
        }
} ;
```

And newer GCCs like 7.3 and 8.2 understand delete without &

```
// this is okay for modern GCC
for ( std::vector< safeptr< Item > >::const_iterator it = items.begin () ; it != items.end () ; ++ it )
{
        delete *it ;
}

// this works with any GCC
for ( std::vector< safeptr< Item > >::const_iterator it = items.begin () ; it != items.end () ; ++ it )
{
        delete &( *it ) ;
}
```

but GCCs like 4.0.x don’t